# How to get those records whose following each other in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm tyring to fetch those records (`users`) whose following each other. I have following table.

```
    id | follower | following
    --+-----------+----------
    1 |     a     |   c
    2 |     b     |   a
    3 |     a     |   g
    4 |     g     |   b
    5 |     c     |   a
```

### What I'm trying ?

I'm trying simple like operator for the task.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE follower  LIKE '%a%' OR following LIKE '%a%'
```

### Result

```
    id | follower | following
    --+-----------+----------
    1 |     a     |   c
    2 |     b     |   a
    3 |     a     |   g
    4 |     c     |   a
```

Above query is working fine as per the logic and `like` operator, but i wanted to fetch those records whose follow each other. Means in above result i need only first and last record, because `a` and `c` are following each other.

### I need

```
    id | follower | following
    --+-----------+----------
    1 |     a     |   c
    2 |     c     |   a
```

Can anyone guide me how can i fetch this kind of record, I would like appreciate if someone help me. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select t1.* 
     from thetable t1 
     join thetable t2 
     on t1.follower = t2.following and  t2.follower = t1.following
```

**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b64ff/1)**

**UPDATE:**

If you interest of user 'a'

```
 select t1.* 
    from t t1 
    join t t2 
    on t1.follower = t2.following and  t2.follower = t1.following 
    where 'a' in (t1.follower,t1.following,t2.follower,t2.following)
```

**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40de6/2)**

Comment: Very good logic, can you kindly also add some details and it will be more useful if i add where clause for follower value ('follower = a') and query return me the result. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 2):

Try these.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (follower='a' AND following='c') OR (follower='c' AND following='a')
```

Your goal is to retrieve both users who are following each other right? In these query, it will select whether `a` is following `c` or `c` is following `a`.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP knows the result in advance